# Remover elemento do de um vetor em C# e não deixar o vetor com um espaço em branco?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Preciso remover um elemento de um vetor com 5 elementos, e não pode ficar com espaço vazio no vetor.

Preciso remover pelo índice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não dá de forma eficiente. Pode fazer isto:

```
var array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
array = array.Where(item => item != 3).ToArray(); //retira o 4o. elemento
```

Se não quiser usar LINQ:

```
var array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
array = = Array.FindAll(numbers, x => x != 3).ToArray(); //retira o 4o. elemento
```

Ou pode fazer um método de extensão para ter um [`removeAt()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeat?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_RemoveAt_System_Int32_)(que existe em um List) no `Array`:

```
public static T[] RemoveAt<T>(this T[] source, int index) {
    T[] dest = new T[source.Length - 1];
    if(index > 0) Array.Copy(source, 0, dest, 0, index);
    if(index < source.Length - 1) Array.Copy(source, index + 1, dest, index, source.Length - index - 1);
    return dest;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Array/RemoveAt2.cs).

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457501/221800).

Nem mesmo uma lista conseguiria fazer isso de forma eficiente. Uma lista ligada daria eficiência, até certo ponto, resolveria a questão da remoção, mas pioraria outras situações.

Answer (score 2):

A complementar a resposta já existente, talvez valha a pena rever a necessidade de utilizar um array. Quando se lida com adição e remoção de elementos, é interessante utilizar um tipo de coleção. Da documentação, veja [como escolher o tipo ideal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/selecting-a-collection-class) para o que está lidando.

Não há como [redimensionar uma array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx) sem um alto preço. Você deve criar uma array totalmente nova com a cópia dos itens. É o que faz o `Array.Resize()` no [final das contas](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,156e066ecc4ccedf), veja:

```
T[] newArray = new T[newSize];
Array.Copy(larray, 0, newArray, 0,  larray.Length > newSize? newSize : larray.Length);
array = newArray;
```

Em casos que você tenha um tamanho fixo de itens e precisa de performance, utilizar um array pode ser vantajoso, principalmente se precisa acessar itens várias vezes. Veja o [teste de *benchmarking*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/454923/6241184) feito no SOen:

```
List/foreach: 3054ms (589725196)
Array/foreach: 1860ms (589725196)
```

Para guardar dados específicos como um bitmap de uma imagem, uma array é o que você procura. Perceba que são casos bem específicos. Na maioria das vezes utilizará um `List<T>` ao invés de um array nesses propósitos.

É importante notar que [por baixo dos panos](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs.html) o `List<T>` utiliza um array:

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, System.Collections.IList, IReadOnlyList<T>
{
    private T[] _items;
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use este 'for' abaixo. Ele removerá o valor do índice, e cada item do vetor irá uma posição para trás, deixando o último item como nulo.

```
     int[] vetor = new int[5];

     private void remove(int indice)
     {
          for(int i = indice; i < vetor.length-1; i++)
          {
                vetor[i] = vetor[i+1];
          }
          vetor[vetor.length-1] = null;
     }
```

No final, você terá um vetor com 5 espaços sendo que apenas o último será nulo. Para retirar o espaço nulo, você pode utilizar alguma variável para representar a quantidade de espaços no vetor e diminuir um com o `'qtd--;'`, ou simplesmente instanciar um novo vetor, realizando a cópia dos valores através de outro 'for'.